# Uncaught Syntax Error. Unexpexcted end of input

Tags: javascript, php

I have this javascript file that is calling a php file to return a JSON string. Chrome dev tools is throwing the error at line 10 in the javascript code. I know the error relates to a missing bracket but for the life of my and 3 other people who have looked at it the syntax is correct.

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
var listings = [];
var json;
var url = "getListing.php";
request.open("GET", url, true);
request.send();
request.onreadystatechange = function(e)
{
if(request.readyState == 4){
    json = JSON.parse(request.responseText);

    for(var x = 0; x < json.length; x++){
        var list = new listingInfo();
        list.category = json[x].category;
        list.date = json[x].dateListed;
        list.description = json[x].description;
        list.id = json[x].listingID;
        list.title = json[x].title;
        list.userID = json[x].userID;
        listings.push(list);
    }   
}
console.log(listings);
}
```

here is the php file

```
<?php
session_start();
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "listAdmin", "hermes");
if(!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("GregsList", $con)
    or die("Unable to select database:" . mysql_error());

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Listings WHERE userID = '$_SESSION[userID]' ORDER BY dateListed DESC");

#converts to json
$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
        $rows[] = $r;
}

#If you want to see if correct json is printing use ---> print json_encode($rows);

return json_encode($rows);
?>
```

Comment: Its not the json content where the mistake is, is it?

Comment: log request.responseText to see if valid

Comment: could you please insert a console.log before JSON.parse with: console.log(request.responseText)

Comment: I have have checked the php file and it indeed returns JSON.

Comment: The log output nothing so an empty string.

Comment: I see that in your php script you use POST and in ajax request you use GET

Comment: Changed them both the Get to a Post in the javascript. Same result.

Comment: In your php script I don't see where you output the json.

Comment: i added the wrong php file earlier. (I'm a bit tired). I added the correct one now.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40486/discussion-between-emil-condrea-and-carter)

Comment: have you tried to replace return json_encode with print json_encode ?

Comment: I have and I indeed get the JSOn I want.

Comment: have you tried placing the `{` on the same line as `function(e)`? Javascript is a little funny about newlines when it comes to function definitions if I remember correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

request.readyState == 4 is not enough you should add request.status== 200
In your php script replace `return json_encode($rows);` with `print json_encode($rows);`

Comment: you should register the callback function request.onreadystatechange = function(e) before sending the request request.send()